# Parametros entre URL's

Tags: java, jsf, spring, primefaces

Buen día!

No encuentro la solución al siguiente problema.

Tengo una Intranet, la cual consume otro proyecto(Pagina web) y la muestra dentro de un IFrame.
La cuestión es ¿Cómo puedo recuperar los parametros de la URL de la pagina de Intranet dentro del IFrame con Java?

Estoy implementando JSF 2.2 con Primefaces 5.0 y Spring Web MVC 4.0.1 bajo un proyecto maven.

Adjunto la pantalla de ejemplo para que me puedan comprender mejor...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buenas bienvenido a **StackOverflow** en español por favor antes de preguntar primero ve [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y revisa también [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) edita tu pregunta y mejorarla para tener una respuesta que realmente te ayude.

Answer (score 2):

No creo que puedas hacerlo del lado de servidor, pero se me ocurre que podes pasar los parametros al iframe directamente al momento de armarlo y agregarlos a la URL de src.

```
<iframe src="url?usuario={usuario}">
```

Donde {usuario} es la forma en Spring de traer un GET.

O sino desde el iframe con JavaScript usando:

```
<script> 
url = parent.document.URL; 
//Lo que necesites hacer... 
</script>
```